# internal-sftp -u 002 is ignored for copied files

Tags: sftp, umask, chroot

I configured OpenSSH like this

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftp
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 002
    AuthorizedKeysFile    /home/sftp/ssh/%u
    ChrootDirectory %h
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

This configuration is working, but there is one problem: Files or folders which are copied from local drive to sftp keep their permissions (usually `755`) and no other `sftp-user` has access to them.

The other `sftp-users` only have full permissions if someone creates a folder or file or copies a file with 775 permissions.

Is there a way that all files in the `sftp-directory` have `775` permissions?
At the moment I'm using `chmod -R 775 /home/sftp/files/` to set it manually, but this isn't the solution i would like to have...

Thanks

Comment: Is there a limited set of tools the users use to upload the files?

Comment: The MAC-users are using Cyberduck, for Windows we're using FileZilla and I'm running Linux Mint and use Nemo (the built in filemanager).

Answer (score 1):

With this setup it is not possible, because `umask` is not enough strong tool to force permissions if the original permission is lower. There are few solutions how to get on with this:

- First of them is your mentioned `chmod`, which you would need to run periodically to have all users accessible all files.
- The other solution is `-m` switch for `sftp-server`, which solves this issue by forcing exact permissions on newly uploaded files. But this feature is not upstream, but it is available at least in RHEL/Fedora especially for this use case.

Comment: Okay, installing RHEL or Fedora is no option because it's running on a WD MyCloud. Then I think I have to write a little script which is watching for new files and chmodding them. At the moment I'm running Debian, is there really no other solution as this 2 mentioned by you?

Comment: @Joriktos Another, but still the same possibility is to rebuild openssh-package (or at least sftp-server) from source with patch from https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1844

Comment: I tried this, but it isn't working. If i try to connect with sftp it instantly responds with "Connection closed"